# Compare dates when 00h using new Date()

Tags: javascript

I have this code that works fine except when comparing to midnight. 23hours should evaluate to <= than 00h. In this case I am just using integers since `getHours()` returns an integer too. What is the correct way to handle this?

```
var starting_hour = 23;
var ending_hour = new Date().getHours() //0

console.log(starting_hour <= ending_hour); //23 <= 0 false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ending_hour` is `0`, replace it with `24` and then do your check.

```
var ending_hour = new Date().getHours();
if (ending_hour == 0) {
    ending_hour = 24;
}
console.log(check_adhour >= starting_hour && check_adhour <= ending_hour);
```

Comment: thank you, I used a small piece of code to reproduce the problem. I need to make comparisons like if(check_adhour >= starting_hour && check_adhour <= ending_hour){} so this will not solve the issue

Comment: I've updated the answer with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> thank you, I used a small piece of code to reproduce the problem. I need to make evaluations like if(check_adhour >= starting_hour && check_adhour <= ending_hour){} so this will not solve the issue

then your logic is different:

```js
const checkHour = (check_adhour, starting_hour, ending_hour) => (starting_hour < ending_hour) ? 
  check_adhour >= starting_hour && check_adhour <= ending_hour : 
  check_adhour >= starting_hour || check_adhour <= ending_hour;
```

usually you try to check wether `check_adhour` is between start and end, but over night, when `start > end` you want to exclude the time between them and take everything else; the evening after the start, and the morning before end.